# Easier way to use both external module's CDN and packages in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

In `sveltekit` I have my common `js` files that run on both client and server. This will reuse the same code on both the server and client side.

This uses the `moment.js` module.

(This is just an example where both CDN and npm exist. I actually use `date-fns`.)

Anyway, I want to run it as a CDN in the client environment and bundle and operate the node package on the server.

So my common js file originally looked like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export const mylib = () => {
  return moment().format();
};
```

The `sveltekit` page also uses `moment.js`:

```
<script>    
    import moment from 'moment';
</script>
<div>
    {moment().format()}
</div>
```

This works fine. Just, my bundle includes `moment.js`.

So I tried several things. And I succeeded in the following way. But it's incredibly dirty.

First, I imported the CDN in `app.html` and created an onload event:

```
<script async defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.4/moment.min.js" onload="momentLoad()"></script>
<script>
    window.momentWaits = [];
    const momentLoad = () => {
        for(const momentWait of window.momentWaits){
            momentWait();
        }
        delete window.momentWaits;
    };
</script>
```

And change `moment.js` in `package.json` from devDependencies to runtime dependencies.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.29.4"
    }
}
```

And set `build.rollupOptions.external` in `vite.config.js`.

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['moment']
        }
    },
});
```

And my common js file became like this:

```
let moment = null;
if(typeof window == 'undefined') {
  (async () => import('moment').then((res) => moment = res.default))();
}else {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const w = window;

  if(w.moment){
    moment = w.moment;
  }else{
    w.momentWaits.push(() => {
      moment = w.moment;
    });
  }
}

export const mylib = () => {
  if(!moment){
    console.log('not yet.');
    return;
  }
  return moment().format();
};
```

As above, if `typeof window == 'undefined'` is used when checking the browser environment, an error occurs saying that `await` was used at the top level when building `vite`, so it was set as a function. Changing `browser` to `$app/environment` solved it:

```
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
let moment;
if(!browser) {
  moment = (await import('moment')).default;
}else {
  // ...
}
```

However, my js file can be executed in an environment other than `svelte`, so I do not do it.

Finally, the `svelte` page changes:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let moment = null;
    onMount(async () => {

        if(window.moment){
            moment = window.moment;
        }else{
            window.momentWaits.push(() => {
                moment = window.moment;
            });
        }

    });
</script>
<div>
    {#if moment}
        {moment().format()}
    {:else}
        wait...
    {/if}
</div>
```

As you can see, it's very dirty. But it works. I'm sure there is a much easier way than this. I want to find it.

In particular, if there is an option to ignore some errors during the build process and keep building, it seems to save a lot of code.

I also suspect that the reason there is no `moment` in the `onMount` event yet is because of the script tag's `async` and  `defer` attribute. Is there a better event than `onMount`?